# using clock() (or similar) function to find time of execution when there are multiple processes

Tags: process, clock, timing

I want to use a function, like clock(), to find the execution time of a particular piece of code. But if there are multiple threads/processes, then would those getting scheduled in between affect the output of the clock() function?

Example code:
process 1

```
int main()
{
 clock_t t1,t2;
 t1=clock();
 //Long code
 t2=clock();
 float diff ((float)t2-(float)t1);
 cout<<diff<<endl;
 system ("pause");
 return 0;
}
```

My question is, if another process gets scheduled while the long code is running, does the clock function count the cycles used for the other program also? If yes, what is an alternative to get the exact time of execution of a piece of code

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. There are many other processes running alongside your code that will affect the execution speed (due to scheduling as you point out). In addition, you code itself may use the disk, network, etc so the CPU usage time for your process may not make sense. What you may want to do this run the timing analysis for the program a large number of times on the same system and same load and take an average from that.